# Как написать bb коды?

Tags: javascript

Вот решил для формы сообщений написать bb коды, но не знаю, готовые не предлагать, нужна как бы суть или пример вот!

Answer (score 1):

Суть: на стороне клиента при выделении текста и нажатии на кнопку текст обрамляется bb-кодом. На стороне сервера: принятый текст обрабатывается `htmlspecialchars()` и пишется в БД. При выводе идет замена некоторых bb-кодов регулярками (код `[script]...[/script]` трогать необязательно ;) ).

> готовые не предлагать ... нужна суть или пример

А в качестве примера погуглите готовый вариа... шутка. =)

Answer (score 0):

Парсить регулярными выражениями. А причем здесь жаваскрипт)?

Comment: На стороне сервера парсить [конечными автоматами][1] чтобы избежать ситуации с незакрытыми тегами


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82